# SystemJS and SignalR

Tags: signalr, systemjs, jspm

Has anyone gotten SystemJS and SignalR to work together?
I have been trying to use SystemJS (from jspm) to load SignalR, but no matter what I do, there is always a race condition with the async loader. About half the times that it loads, SignalR is not loaded by the time my initialization code runs.

```
System.config({
    baseURL: '/Scripts',
    map: {
        'jquery': '/bundles/jquery',
        'jquery.ui.widget': 'jquery-ui-1.10.4.js',
    },
    meta: {
        '/signalr/hubs': {
            deps: ['jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js']
        }
    }
});
Promise.all([
    System.import('jQuery.FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js'),
    System.import('knockout-3.1.0.debug.js'),
    System.import('/signalr/hubs')
])
.then(function (libs, gg) {
    var ko = libs[1];

    //My init code
    var chat = $.connection.jobProgress;
    // Throws '$.connection is undefined' about half the time
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using signalr package config.

```
System.config({
    baseURL: 'Scripts',
    map: {
            "signalr-jquery": "Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0",
            "signalr": "signalr",
            "jquery": "/bundles/jquery" //I would pull it from jspm also
        },
        meta: {
            "jquery": {
                "format": "cjs"

            },
            "signalr-jquery": {
                "format": "global",
                "deps": ["jquery"]
            }
        },
        packages: {
            "signalr": {
                "format": "global",
                "defaultExtension": false,
                "meta": {
                    "hubs": {
                        "format": "global",
                        "deps": ["signalr-jquery"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
})
```

and import hubs

```
    System.import('signalr/hubs').then(function(hubs) {

   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load it with this configuration:

```
System.config({
    map: {
      'jquery': 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'signalrJquery': 'jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js',
      'signalrHubs': 'jquery.signalR-2.2.0.Hubs.js'
    },
    meta: {
        "jquery-1.10.2.js": { exports: "$" }, 
        signalrJquery: {exports: "$"},
        signalrHubs: {
            deps: ['jquery-1.10.2.js', 'signalrJquery'],
        exports: "$"
    }
});
```

Then fetch it like this:

```
import * as $ from 'signalrHubs';
```

or

```
var $ = require('signalrHubs');
```

Notice that the jquery version in the dependencies is the version that signalr depends on.  The rest of the website can use a newer version if desired.